# Match and retrieve values from another opened workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling creating a VBA code dealing with data retrieval from another opened workbook. I have a main workbook on which the data is manually being fed in from a secondary workbook. I am looking to automate this with a macro that will sit in Personal.XLSB. I am quite new to VBA and I am learning hitting my head to all of these problems.

**Colum E (test5) is the matching criteria**. If column E in the main workbook matches with the column E in the secondary workbook then copy cell D;F;G;H;I;J from secondary workbook into the main workbook.  If there is no match in Colum E there is nothing to be done to that row and it needs to go to next row until it finds a match. I have managed to make a code but it crashes because there is over 1k rows to match. Then I tried something else (see below)

Main Workbook

[image: 1]

Secondary Workbook

[image: 2]

This is the code I was working on but I gave up because I don't understand it. This is just a mess

```
Option Explicit

Sub WithButton()
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim sh_Data As Worksheet '
Dim CellChanged As Integer
Dim LastRow, LastData As Long
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim wb2 As Workbook '


On Error GoTo Handle

With Sh_Record
    If .Range("Z1").Value = "" Then
        .Range("Z1").Value = 0
        CellChanged = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    
    If .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row > .Range("Z1").Value Then
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Second.xlsx")
        Set sh_Data = wb2.Worksheets("data")
        
        CellChanged = .Range("Z1").Value + 1
        LastRow = sh_Data.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        LastData = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If .Range("E" & CellChanged).Value = sh_Data.Range("E" & i) Then
                .Range("D" & CellChanged).Value = sh_Data.Range("D" & i).Value
                .Range("F" & CellChanged).Resize(, 5).Value = sh_Data.Range("F" & i).Resize(, 5).Value
                Found = True
            End If
            If Found = True Or i = LastRow Then
                If CellChanged = LastData Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            If Found = True Then
                Found = False
                CellChanged = CellChanged + 1
            Else
                CellChanged = CellChanged + 1
                End If
                i = 0
            End If
        Next i
        wb2.Close False
        .Range("Z1").Value = CellChanged
    End If
End With
Exit Sub
Handle:
    MsgBox ("Error")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary` object is a more efficient approach to get unique list and compare data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim arrRec, rngRec As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, Sh_Data As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Open second workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Second.xlsx")
    Set Sh_Data = wb2.Worksheets("data")
    ' Read data from sheet
    With Sh_Data
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("A1", .Cells(lastRow, 12))
    End With
    arrData = rngData.Value
    wb2.Close False
    ' Load Dict with data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        objDic(arrData(i, 5)) = i
    Next i    
    Dim Sh_Record As Worksheet, Main_wk As Workbook
    ' Assumes main workbook is opened, get the workbook
    Set Main_wk = Workbooks("SO-77428517.xlsm") ' Modify as needed
    ' Get the sheet
    Set Sh_Record = Main_wk.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Modify as needed
    ' Read data from sheet
    With Sh_Record
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngRec = .Range("D1", .Cells(lastRow, 10)) '**change2**
    End With
    arrRec = rngRec.Value
    ' Comparing Col E
    For i = LBound(arrRec) + 1 To UBound(arrRec)
        sKey = arrRec(i, 2) ' **change2**
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            ' Populate Col D to J if matching
            For j = 4 To 10
                arrRec(i, j-3) = arrData(objDic(sKey), j) ' **change2**
            Next
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update main workbook
    rngRec.Value = arrRec
    Set objDic = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

---

**Update**

> Question:  I am looking to create a rule that if there is already values in the main workbook to not copy the values from the secondary WB.

```vb
            For j = 4 To 10
                If Len(arrRec(i, j))=0 Then arrRec(i, j) = arrData(objDic(sKey), j)
            Next
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I have encountered a problem. If the second workbook has extra data in column E which is not matching with what is in column E in the main workbook it will throw an error. I will have to figure out how to overpass this as the second workbook always gonna have data wich is not present in the main one. I will try this when I am back in work tomorrow night. Fingers crossed

Comment: There is a typo. I have update the code which is marked with `**update**`.

Comment: I have manage to adapt this to our open workbook. There is one thing that battles me. I know should of mention it in my main question but I tough I will be able to adjust it myself but I believe working with Dictionary Object it makes it difficult. I am looking to create a rule that if there is already values in the main workbook to not copy the values from the secondary WB. At the minute it overrides every cell on that row if Column E is matching.

Comment: Why Dict makes it difficult?

Comment: I have not used Dictionary Object before and probably I am just confusing myself. But the only thing I am trying now is to add a statement as IF there is a value in cell in the main WB to not copy the information from secondary WB and fill only the cells that are empty. This is all because at the minute it overrides everything in main WB if column E matches between the books. Appreciate your help so far you are a LEGEND.

Comment: See the updated code.

Comment: Hello Taller. I have adapted this to our main workbook and it works perfectly. I am just facing a problem when I run it.  I have formulas in columns A to C and when I run it. It will delete the formulas in those columns (A to C).  Could you guide me on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: See the code which is marked with `**change2**`.